# $\int_0^1(1+\log(x))\sin(x)dx$ How to solve this Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\limits_0^1(1+\log(x))\sin(x)dx$$

Someone has challenged me to solve this, 
I solved it without bounds, I have no idea how to do it with those limits..

Is $u=1+\log(x)$ right substituion?
or $x=e^{-u}$ ?

Comment: no elementary solution here\

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts, it is not difficult to check that $\int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\sin(x)\,dx$ is given by the difference between the cosine integral of one and the Euler-Mascheroni constant; the other piece is trivial. Notice that:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\sin(x)\,dx &=& \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n+1}\log(x)\,dx\\&=&-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^2(2n+1)!}\\&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n)\cdot(2n)!}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Integration by parts is not so trivial here right? because you need two diverging pieces to cancel, for which in turn you need the asymptotic expansion of $\text{CosIntegral}(x) $around $x=0$...

Comment: @tired: one has to be careful and take $\color{red}{1-}\cos x$ as a primitive for $\sin x$. Anyway, I was meaning that the "trivial piece" is $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x)\,dx$.

Comment: It was $$\int_0^1 (logx +1).sinx$$ not $$\int_0^1 (logx).sinx$$

Comment: @CuriousSciDude: yes, I know, but the difference is just $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x)\,dx$ that is trivial to compute.